# Is it possible to check if `panic` is set to `abort` while a library is compiling?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

It may be not a good idea or not idiomatic, but let's assume that for some reason a library relies on [`catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) for its business logic.

Can I somehow warn (by failing the compilation with an error message?) a user of this library if [they set `panic = "abort"`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-profile-sections) in `Cargo.toml` of their "terminal" crate?

I was thinking about checking some environment variable in `build.rs` but [can't find any variables with this information](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html).

Comment: How would this hypothetical library deal with the user calling `exit` or the process being killed via the OS? It's definitely not a good idea.

Comment: It won't handle these situations at all I guess. That's one reason why such a library is not a good idea in practice - it's a theoretical question.

Comment: You may be able to check RUSTFLAGS in a build.rs https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html and try to amend `-C panic=$PROFILE` to `-C panic=unwind`, but I'm not sure it'd work. See the original PR for panic=abort: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/36794

Comment: Note, I'm not advocating subtly altering behavior, my suspicion is it'll cause a linker error.

Comment: @LinearZoetrope `RUSTFLAGS` is for the user to pass through extra flags; it's not set in a typical build. As far as I know, Cargo doesn't tell the build script what flags it's passing to rustc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this unstable code in your binary or library to cause an error when `-C panic=abort` is specified:

```rust
#![feature(panic_unwind)]
extern crate panic_unwind;
```

Which causes this helpful error when the wrong panic strategy is used:

```text
error: the linked panic runtime `panic_unwind` is not compiled with this crate's panic strategy `abort`
```

When the panic strategy is correct, the `extern crate` declaration is redundant, but does nothing. When the panic strategy is wrong, it causes a linking error since you can't have two different panic strategy crates in the same binary. Since this check happens when crates are linked, note that if a library is never actually used by the top-level crate, then the check isn't run. (but this is a good thing: if your library is unused, then there is no need for this check anyways!)

Also, this error happens very late in the compilation process, so while `cargo build` will error out, `cargo check` won't complain since `cargo check` doesn't check for linking errors for performance reasons.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this on the stable channel.